# Error displaying laravel passport api data with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, fetch, laravel-passport

I am facing an issue, when I retrieve data from a Laravel passport API with ReactJs, but when I try to display them or send to another component, I have an error. Below is the code that I used.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});   

    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`);

    const myInit = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "default",
    };

    useEffect(() => {

       async function fetchUserData()
      {
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/user", myInit)
          .then((response) => {
            const data = response.json();

            setUser(data);
          });
      }
      fetchUserData();
    }, [])
    console.log(user.name)
    console.log(user);
```

This is the error shown in the console:
[image: Image for console.log]

Answer (score 0):

There is one main issue i. e. that [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) is asynchronous and therefore returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you either have to `await` that or use [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to chain the continuation. Also, you should check the HTTP status code of the response, to be sure you get the data back. Last but not least you should catch the errors [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) might throw e.g. when your server is offline etc. using either a try-catch block (when working with `async/ await`) or [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) when chaining `Promise`s. I'd recommend to either stick with `async/ await` or chaining. Most people prefer `async/ await` since it enables to program as if the calls were happening synchronously.

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState({});

const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`);

const myInit = {
  method: "GET",
  headers: myHeaders,
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "default",
};

useEffect(() => {

  async function fetchUserData() {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/user", myInit)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`Status code '${response.status}': Failed to retrieve user details.`);
        }
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(data => setUser(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }
  fetchUserData();
}, [])
console.log(user.name)
console.log(user);
```

Comment: I tried but I always get undefined in console